# Not able uninstall java openjdk version "11.0.2"

Tags: java, mac

java - version show java 11 as follow

```
mymac:~ mymac$ java -version 

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 

OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

When run "which java" on my mac : i get following

```
mymac:~ mymac$ which java 

/usr/bin/java
```

/usr/bin/java is symbolic link to

java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

But i am not able find this symbolic link and uninstall java

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this with this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk
```

Which deletes the openjdk-11.0.2.jdk file to whioch the link pointed to.